# Why doesn't CGRectInfinite intersect any other rects?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-graphics

I expected this:

```
CGRectIntersection(CGRectInfinite, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
```

to return:

```
{{0,0},{10,10}}
```

however it treated the two rects as non-intersecting and returned `CGRectNull` instead.

As far as I can see, given that the infinite rect intersects all space, the intersect between it and any rect *R* should just be *R*.

Am I missing something here, or is this just a quirk/bug in the frameworks?

Comment: Works on iOS version 7.1.  Which OS and version are you testing on?

Comment: Seems like if you expect it to do that you could just as easily assume it intersects all rects.

Comment: What is your evidence that CGRectNull is returned?

Comment: LLDB variable inspection / evaluating the quoted code in the debugger was producing the incorrect result. The same expression in a test program evaluated to the correct result. Looks like an issue with LLDB, not the frameworks. Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: `CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInfinite, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))` was also returning `NO` in the debugger. However, explicitly casting the arguments' types produced the expected result. Looks the debugger it was incorrectly passing one of the arguments.